# Display by category in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code which groups my users by role.  It all works well but I feel I could have done this more elegantly.  Is there a better way?

```
<?php $userrole = '';?>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) : ?>
    <?php if ($user->userrole != $userrole) :
        $userrole = $user->userrole; ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?=$userrole?></td>
            </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: using short tags `<?=` is now considered bad practice and disabled as default.

Comment: This is displaying the roles, but it isn't displaying the rest of the user information.